# How to get the file code in php for programming files manager

Tags: java, php, file, base64, icons

I am trying to programming a file manager by php language.
Its problem is how to get file icons (**getting icons from the server not from a client**).
Can I get the icons from Java and convert them to text base64 and use exec () in php to get base64 text?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class IconBase64 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String s = fileName;

        File file = new File(s);

        sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder sf = sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.getShellFolder(file);

        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(sf.getIcon(true));

        String base64Image = /* convert ImageIcon to base 64 ??? */

        System.out.print( base64Image );

    }

}
```

Can we do something like this?

Comment: *Can I get the icons from Java and convert them to text base64 and use exec () in php to get base64 text?* - Yes.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Is there a Java class for it's?